# URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-fql

Whenever I make a call to facebook server to fetch user data using FQL, 10% of the time I get

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

I am not able to reproduce this error. Below is the traceback:

```
File "/home/fb.py", line 250, in get_data()
   return json.load(urlopen(URL, params))

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
   return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
   response = self._open(req, data)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
   '_open', req)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
   result = func(*args)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1169, in https_open
   return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1136, in do_open
   raise URLError(err)

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Any reason why you have a function `xxx()`? Just curious

Comment: Rafe: I changed it for you :)

Comment: Any solutions ? I have the same problem when I tried access a https url. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually created by mismanaged or badly setup firewalls or proxy systems, if you try running your program from a household adsl line or on a simple connection there should be no problem with your code, 104 is the error code thrown back when something inside your local area network has a hissy fit and gives up crying.

Answer (score 1):

Try `cache=None` as client param. It helped me to solve same issue.

```
client = suds.client.Client(url, cache=None)
```